# Want to use the same Javascript (popup) session cookie twice, what values do I change?

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, session-cookies

I have a .swf that we have pop up once per visit on the home page for a few seconds and then disappears. For that I use

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        function popUp(url) { a bunch of java add flash stuff}

function testCookie() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("popupOnceValue=false") > -1) {
        document.cookie = "popupOnceValue=true;";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function popupOnce() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("popupOnceValue") > -1) {
        if (testCookie()) {
            popUp("");
        } 
    } else {
        document.cookie = "popupOnceValue=false;";
        if (testCookie()) {
            popUp("wefinance2.swf");
        }
    }
}

function init() {
    popupOnce();
}

window.onload = init;       



                    </script>
```

this works fabulous. BUT any I literally have tried every combination of variables to make it so that I could do the exact same type of pop up on another page.. but because the cookie is already recognized it doesn't pop up (even though it is a different .swf) so basically I'm asking what should I change in order to be able to use the same popup code twice (popUP, testCookie, popupOnce)?? AGH!

Driving myself crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the cookie names unique to the page URL. You can do this by hard coding a cookie name for each page, or automatically generating the cookie name. The latter is illustrated below.

```
// Generate a cookie name based on the current URL.
function getCookieName() {
    return 'popup_' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
}

function testCookie() {
    // Find the cookie name for the current page.
    var cookieName = getCookieName();
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName) > -1) {
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=true;";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function popupOnce() {
    // Find the cookie name for the current page.
    var cookieName = getCookieName();
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName) > -1) {
        if (testCookie()) {
            popUp("");
        } 
    } else {
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=false;";
        if (testCookie()) {
            popUp("wefinance2.swf");
        }
    }
}
```